# Extracting pandas timedelta instance attribute, days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, series, timedelta

I have a pandas Series, `ages` consisting of pandas timedelta's.
Printing the first element of `ages[0]` looks like this: `Timedelta('218 days 22:46:00')`

Now, if I write the following code: `age[0].days`, it prints like this: `218`

I would like to apply `.days` to every element in the pandas Series, `ages`.

I wrote this code to do so, but running it outputs errors.

In:

```
ageNew = []
for i in range(len(age)):
    ageNew.append(age[i].days)
```

Out:

```
KeyError: 12
```

I looked up the error, and it mentions dicts however I am using lists...what does the error mean and how can I apply `.days` to all the elements in `ages`.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access [`pd.Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html):

```
s = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta('218 days 22:46:00'), pd.Timedelta('400 days 22:46:00')])

res = s.dt.days

0    218
1    400
dtype: int64
```